# How to create an android app for store's digital scale

Tags: java, android, qr-code

Is there any way to write an app for store's digital scales , to get some data like weight , price ...
and generate a QR code to pay for the shopping basket ?
the digital scale has WiFi , QRCode reader port and printer .
and i wanna connect the digital scale to android tablet .

this is the device picture :[image]

Comment: You can make android App to read QR code and do certain steps/process according to that

Comment: there is no QR code in printed recipe , and all i want is to replace an android tablet with the laptop that handles the customer's shopping basket. there is always a laptop beside those digital scales , and i wanna replace them.

Comment: Can you please explain the `purpose` of the laptop? like why do you need a laptop with this scaling machine? Does the laptop created `invoice` or something else?

Comment: for uploading excel file into scale , and getting parameters like weight , and when you make the system automated , u need a database that is connected with scales, so you need laptop, now most stores here are running their system with laptop, but none of them can use android/IOS device instead of windows based PCs.

Comment: You can not eliminate laptop in this case, but you can reduce the uses of laptop. if you know any other languages, for example - you can make the laptop upload excel to server and you can access those excel files in your android phone/tablet same as you can read database directly in your tablet